# How to map properties on the CouchDB document to java model object?

Tags: spring-boot, couchdb, cloudant

I have within a database a set of documents in CouchDB where their structure is as follow :

```
    {
      "_id": "adebafb022857385a4c970b0f0000349",
      "_rev": "2-19d78f4d8d6386bfbe7b2c03b5213830",
      "street_number": "20",
      "street_name": "B.Baker St",
      "city_name": "Marylebone",
      "zip_code": "2550",
      "status": "active"
    }
```

as you can see the properties are not camel-cased, I have tried to make the mapping using JsonProperty, however, I get null value in all properties except for status property.

[image]

I have pushed the code in this repo [link](https://github.com/agentjoseph007/couch_mapping)

Any help is much appreciated

Regarding the CouchDB, I using a docker container with CouchDB image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used `com.google.code.gson` dependency with `@SerializedName` as follows:

```
package com.example.couch_mapping.model;

import com.google.gson.annotations.*;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class AddressDto {
    @SerializedName("_id")
    String id;

    @SerializedName("_rev")
    String revision;

    @SerializedName("street_number")
    String streetNumber;

    @SerializedName("street_name")
    String streetName;

    @SerializedName("city_name")
    String cityName;

    @SerializedName("zip_code")
    String zipCode;

    String status;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is the same as https://github.com/cloudant/java-cloudant/issues/536 the values are not deserialized correctly because `JsonProperty` is a  *Jackson* annotation, but the library is using *Gson* deserialization.

The Gson equivalent annotation is `@SerializedName`.